# How upload expansion file with apk in Google play

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have to play local video in my application but it has 200 MB video size. And Google play not allow to more then 50MB apk file.

This application is for both phone and tablets. Hence, I need to upload video as per resolution wise. in short, I need to upload two folder in Google play for phione video and tablet video.

How i can upload extra files with apk in Google play and how can I use
those uploaded files in my application while user download app from
Google play ?

Answer (score 5):

You have a step by step process to upload the APK which is more then 50 MB http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html.

From my experience loading more then 50 MB is very bad experience for user. Rather you can upload the video in You Tube and show it. You can refer this app form google play for more details

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nike.ntc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5uaWtlLm50YyJd

Comment: If it solves your question please check it, I am improving my profile my answering questions here, It will improve my profile